# Can I make the <div> size include child <div> with position:absolute?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm building a website and having some problem.

if the HTML code is like:

```
<div class="parent">    
    <div class="child">
         **contents1**
    </div>

     **contents2**
</div>
```

and the CSS stylesheet like:

```
.parent{ position: relative;}
.child{ position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 20px;}
```

In that situation, the border of *'parent'* doesn't contain the area of *'child'*,
 but only the bounding box of contents 2.

Is there a way to solve it?

I want that the bounding box of parent includes its children's bounding boxes regardless of their position attribute.

I may be able to calculate the size of parent through *JQuery*,

but I think there is a way I can do just with CSS.

Hope to get a positive answeres.

Thanks!

Comment: Non taken, would you please describe more?

Comment: It's not possible with CSS only. An absolute positioned element is loose from it's parent. But if you tell, what the final layout should be, we maybe find a solution with floating elements or some other way to get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position:absolute;` takes the element out of document flow - that's pretty much the point of the property.

If your `.child` has a static height however, you can get away by applying an appropriate padding to its parent like so:

```
.parent{position:relative;padding-top:60px;} /*(40+10*2)px*/
.child{position:absolute;top:10px;left:20px;height:40px;}
```

[Fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/Tuy3v/1/)

Chances are absolute positioning has been abused if you still want to account for `.child` dimensions and you could probably get away with an alternative (hard to suggest something without better context)

I'd generally suggest you not use [anonymous blocks](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level) either.